# How to generate load for a sharepoint application with windows based authentication using Jmter?

Tags: sharepoint, jmeter, load-generator

I need to generate load to a share point application which runs on windows based authentication. Using JMeter I was not able to recognize the windows authentication popup.

The analysis of the application server performance can be done using server monitoring listener in Jmeter or deferred server analysis tool in share point.
I have problem only in Load generation

If there is any other tool do suggest me

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) to construct a relevant authentication header.

It should be quite enough to deal with [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617)

However if you need to use your machine credentials which is [NTLM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you'll need to do the following:

1. Change implementation of your HTTP Samplers to HTTPClient 3.1 (for digest) or HTTPClient 4 (if you're Sharepoint instance is using Kerberos)
2. Perhaps it worth playing with `http.authentication.preemptive$Boolean` property. In some cases you need to set it to "true"